# Zero-sum differential game

Tags: optimization, game-theory, dynamic-programming, differential-games

We consider a zero sum differnetial game.
Let $x \in (0, M] \subset \mathbb R_{++}$ denote the state and $(u,v) \in [0,x]$ the control of player 1 and 2 respectively with $u + v \leq x$.
Denote the lower $\underline V(x)$ and upper $\overline V(x)$ value by a Hamilton-Jacobi-Bellman-Isaacs equation
\begin{align}
r\underline V(x) = \max_u \min_v \{\ln(u) - \underline V'(x)(u + v)\}    
\end{align}
Consider the first order condition of player 2 for the lower value
\begin{align}
 - \underline V'(x) < 0 \Rightarrow v^* = x
\end{align}
If $v^* = x$, then $u^* = 0$ such that $\underline V(x) = -\infty$.

For the upper value I'm not too sure.
\begin{align}  
r\overline V(x) =  \min_v \max_u \{\ln(u) - \overline V'(x)(u + v)\}   
\end{align}
Consider the first order condition of player 1 for the upper value
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{u^*} - \underline V'(x) = 0 \Leftrightarrow \underline V'(x) = \frac{1}{u^*}
\end{align}
The maximized HJBI becomes
\begin{align}  
r\overline V(x) =  \min_v \left\{\ln(u^*) - 1 - \frac{v}{u^*}\right\}   
\end{align}
The first order conditions of the second player then reads
\begin{align}
- \frac{1}{u^*} < 0  \Rightarrow v^* = x.
\end{align}
Again $v^* = x$, then $u^* = 0$ such that $\overline V(x) = -\infty$.

Is the reasoning correct? I was wondering if we may argue that for the upper value player 1 chooses $u^*$ first and then $v^* = x - u^*$. Then
\begin{align}  
r\overline V(x) =  \ln(u^*) - \frac{x}{u^*}
\end{align}
Now guess linear control $u^* = Ax$
\begin{align}  
&r\overline V(x) =  \ln(Ax) - \frac{1}{A}\\   
&r\overline V'(x) = \frac{r}{Ax} = \frac{1}{x} \Leftrightarrow A = r
\end{align}
The upper value is then rather given by $\overline V(x) =  (\ln(rx) - \frac{1}{r})/r$.

**Edit**: I tend to believe that $\underline V(x) = \overline V(x) = V(x)$ and that we cannot impose an implcit timing of moves but, must consider the first order conditions simultaneously.
So we either have
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{u^*} - V'(x) = 0 &\Leftrightarrow V'(x) = \frac{1}{u^*}\\
- \underline V'(x) < 0 &\Rightarrow v^* = x - u^*
\end{align}
Such that 
\begin{align}
 V(x) =  \frac{1}{r}\left(\ln(rx) - \frac{1}{r}\right)
\end{align}
Can someone confirm that?

Or simply $V(x) = -\infty$ for $v^* = x$. What's correct? The latter seems to make more sense. Because player 2 only cares about minimizing such that he consumes the entire state.